# After deploy change app Flutter for React Native on Android and Apple Store?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile-application

I want to know if after deploying my mobile application build with Flutter, I can easily change for an application made with React Native or another framework? And user with my application have just to update ?

Or the store (android and apple) will see that as a new project?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct, you just upload a new version with your new framework as it would be a standard update. So you have to have the same bundle id/package name and build number/name. And also don't forget to sign the apk with the same Keystore for android!